# PackageNotFoundError: cudnn while passing the arguments in a text file

Tags: anaconda, conda, cudnn

I am running the following command -

```
conda install -y --file b.txt -p <env_path>
```

Contents of b.txt -

```
cudnn=6.0.0
```

I get the following error -

```
    Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - cudnn 6.0.0

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

cudnn is part of [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cudnn) channel.

However, when I run this, things work fine and cudnn is installed -

```
conda install -y cudnn=6.0.0 -p <env_path>
```

Any pointers on why passing it via file is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing cudnn-6.0.0 to cudnn-6.0-0 worked!